# Postgresql: column of type "INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH" doesn't return expected value if db intervalstyle is set to 'sql_standard'

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc, intervals

My application writes "P7Y2M" to a table column `VALIDITY` of type `INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH`.
I will list the outputs I'm getting, depending on the `intervalstyle` set on the database AND the means I'm using (`psql` console of my Docker container or the db console of my IntelliJ IDE).

For value: `P7Y2M`

| intervalstyle | Docker container psql | IntelliJ IDE (JDBC conn) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| postgres (default) | 7 years 2 mons | 7 years 2 mons 0 days 0 hours 0 mins 0.0 secs |
| sql_standard | 7-2 | 0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 0 mins 0.0 secs |

The thing is, the application queries the table for the value and gets `0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 0 mins 0.0 secs` back and of course treats that as `0` and doesn't produce expected results.

I suspect the JDBC connection itself because both IDE DataSource connection and the code itself are depending on it. I'm out of other ideas. So if anyone has experienced anything similar, please share your thoughts.

Comment: Looks indeed like a bug in the JDBC driver. I can reproduce this with a different JDBC based query tool.

Comment: I just got an idea to maybe try another driver version (not sure if it's going to work, even less that may fix the problem). Thank you for trying and confirming the reproduction.